# Ruby on Rails - Why the code inside my controller is not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I retrieved a Web API coded in Ruby on Rails.

I'm trying to be aware of the code of my predecessor, but fails to understand why my route does not lead to my controller.

My route is configured this way:

```
resources :bars, :defaults => { :format => 'json' } do
    member do
      post :subscription
      delete :subscription
      get :bar_comments
      get :events
      get :default_event
      get :dates
      post :store_sections
      put :store_sections
      get :store_sections, to: 'bars#store_sections_index'
      post :tables
      put :tables
      get :tables, to: 'bars#tables_index'
      post :traffic_breakpoint
      get :traffic
      get :entrance_traffic
      put :auto_events
      get :fake_counter
      post :fake_counter
      put :stripe_info
    end
    collection do
      get :favorites
      get :test, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
    end
  end
```

I want to catch a get request on bars/favorites url.

Here is how the favorites function is defined on bars_controller

```
def favorites
logger.debug "FAVORITE BARS!!!#####################################################################"
    if current_user.present?
      @bars = Bar.average_join.filter_favorite(current_user)
      render :index
    else
      render json: { error: { error_code: 5, error_message: 'You need to be authentificated' } }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

When I call bars/favorites, here is what I see in terminal and logs:

```
Started GET "/bars/favorites" for 111.111.11.111 at 2017-08-25 22:00:52 +0200
Processing by BarsController#favorites as JSON
  Parameters: {"bar"=>{}}
  AccessToken Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "access_tokens".* FROM "access_tokens"  WHERE "access_tokens"."access_token" = 'ebeddb822e1f36848162818a585df3d0' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 11ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

The route is found and the controller too. If I rename the favorites function in controller, I will get an error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'favorites' could not be found for BarsController):
  app/helpers/sabayon_middleware.rb:25:in `call'
```

I can't understand why my log message (logger.debug "FAVORITE BARS!!!.....) doesn't appear on logs, it's like the favorite function was called but nothing of what is supposed to do happens (inside the function).

Plus I have exactly the same structure for another entity (clubs), and it's just working perfectly. Here is how the clubs route is defined:

```
resources :clubs, :defaults => { :format => 'json' } do
    member do
      post :subscription
      delete :subscription
      get :club_comments
      get :events
      get :default_event
      get :dates
      post :store_sections
      put :store_sections
      get :store_sections, to: 'clubs#store_sections_index'
      post :tables
      put :tables
      get :tables, to: 'clubs#tables_index'
      post :traffic_breakpoint
      get :traffic
      get :entrance_traffic
      put :auto_events
      get :fake_counter
      post :fake_counter
      put :stripe_info
    end
    collection do
      get :favorites
    end
  end
```

And the favorite function in controller:

```
def favorites
logger.debug "FAVORITES CLUBS #####################################################################"
if current_user.present?
  @clubs = Club.average_join.filter_favorite(current_user)
  render :index
else
      render json: {error: {error_code: 5, error_message: 'You need to be authentificated'}}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

In this case everything works perfectly, when I call clubs/favorites I get:

```
Started GET "/clubs/favorites" for 111.111.11.111 at 2017-08-25 22:23:26 +0200
Processing by ClubsController#favorites as JSON
  Parameters: {"club"=>{}}
  AccessToken Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "access_tokens".* FROM "access_tokens"  WHERE "access_tokens"."access_token" = '5835db5eb54c0d05114ceb86688b2a31' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
FAVORITES CLUBS #####################################################################
  Club Load (2.4ms)  SELECT clubs.*, round(AVG (club_comments.rate), 2) AS rate_average, clubs.*, club_subscriptions.id IS NOT NULL AS is_favorite FROM "clubs" LEFT OUTER JOIN club_comments ON club_comments.club_id = clubs.id INNER JOIN club_subscriptions ON club_subscriptions.club_id = clubs.id AND club_subscriptions.user_id = 1 GROUP BY clubs.id, club_subscriptions.id
  Rendered clubs/index.json.jbuilder (4.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 14.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
```

**UPDATE 28.08.2017**

I managed to fix the issue by commenting this line in bars_controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

So I don't understand why `clubs/favorites` is working and `bars/favorites`, but at least I can work now.

**UPDATE 29.08.2017**

As asked by @Leito, here is the content of my Ability Class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    #can :read, :all
    default_abilities
    if user.persisted?
      user_basic_abilities(user)

      if user.admin?
        club_owner_abilities(user)
        can :manage, :all
      elsif user.club_owner?
        club_owner_abilities(user)
      elsif user.user?

      end
    else
      not_connected_abilities
    end
  end

  def default_abilities
    can [:index, :show, :events, :dates, :club_comments, :tables_index, :store_sections_index, :letsencrypt, :fake_counter], Club
    can [:index, :show], Artist
    can [:index, :show, :dates, :tables_index, :premium], Event
    can [:index, :show], Ticket
  end

  def user_basic_abilities(user)
    can [:index, :show, :update, :me, :update_password, :club_comments, :customer, :get_customer, :source, :select_source, :delete_source, :bookings], User, id: user.id
    can :upload, Picture
    can :destroy, Picture, user_id: user.id

    can :create, Booking
    can :share, Booking do |booking|
      booking.owner.id == user.id
    end

    can :show, Booking do |booking|
      booking.user_entrances.where(user_id: user.id).count > 0
    end

    can :subscription, Club
    can :favorites, Club, user_id: user.id

    can :create, ClubComment
    can [:update, :destroy], ClubComment, user_id: user.id

    can [:subscription, :vote], Artist

    can [:favorites, :subscription], Event

    can :create, Cart
    can [:index, :update, :destroy, :cart_items, :user_infos, :order], Cart, user_id: user.id
    can [:payment], Order do |order|
      order.user.id == user.id
    end
  end

  def club_owner_abilities(user)
    can :create, Club
    can :create, Artist

    can :upload, Picture
    can :destroy, Picture, user_id: user.id

    can [:update, :tables, :store_sections, :traffic_breakpoint, :traffic, :entrance_traffic, :default_event, :auto_events], Club, id: user.club_id

    can [:update, :stats, :votes], Artist

    can :create, Event
    can [:update, :destroy, :tables, :default_tables, :bookings], Event, club_id: user.club_id

    can [:create, :update, :destroy], Promotion do |promo|
      promo.event && promo.event.club_id == user.club_id
    end

    can [:receipt, :confirmation_table, :cancelation_table], Booking
    can [:consume, :show, :payments, :refund_payment], Booking do |booking|
      booking.event && booking.event.club_id == user.club_id
    end

    can [:create, :update, :destroy], Ticket do |ticket|
      ticket.event && ticket.event.club_id == user.club_id
    end
  end

  def not_connected_abilities
    can :create, AccessToken
    can [:create, :login], User
    # can :register, MobileDevice
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe a `before_action` on `favorites` is stoping the execution. See that the status code being returned is Completed 404 Not Found.

Comment: Hard to tell, double check the rest of the `routes.rb` file, maybe there is another route that conflicts with yours.  Other then that, test other methods in the `BarsController` and see such as the default ones like `show` or `edit`

Comment: @PhuPhan, show and edit functions/routes are just working great

Comment: @Leito I tried to comment 'before_action :restrict_access, except: [:fake_counter]', but this was breaking all web services. However, I was able to fix the issue by commenting 'load_and_authorize_resource' just below

Comment: Glad we were able to help, if you share the contents of your Ability class and tell us more about the user that's logged in while you are visiting the two pages we can help you further.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load_and_authorize_resource` comes from *cancan* or *cancancan*. These are autorhization gems that limit the records a user has access too. Let's see how *club/favorites* and *bar/favorites* are authorized differently.

From your `Ability` class it appears that the user is missing an authorization on `can :favorites, Bar` similar to the existing:

```
can :favorites, Club, user_id: user.id
```

Depending on how you rescue form `CanCan::AccessDenied` this could explain the response from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

`404` is returned by rails when an active record query fails with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. So I say, either `User` or `Bar` or any other related `find` methods are raising an error (due to not being available in DB).

Comment: I don't think this is the reason because there is no Favorites clubs too in Database.